# JSFiddle.net panels is not displaying any code in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, jsfiddle

I've just started using [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) and there seems to be a problem that the panels are not displaying code in Firefox on opening other users fiddle and in IE it is working fine.

I could't understand what is the issue here.

Here it is in IE
[image: here it is in IE]

Here it is in Firefox
[image: here it is in Firefox]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to clean your cache on mozilla

Comment: updates in jsfiddle codes yesterday can be cause (http://blog.jsfiddle.net/post/39954467099/jsfiddle-updated)